# Dyanamic Text displaying numbers incorrectly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Good afternoon,

I have a .fla file with a movieclip that has a dynamic text box in it. In my .as class file I'm setting the dynamic text's text with `_clip.Score.text = "Points: " + _score.toString()`. This seems like it would work but for some reason the following results happen:

_score | _clip.Score.text
0 | "Points 0"
10 | "Points 10"
20 | "Points 0"
30 | "Points 0"
...

Anyone know any reason this would happen?

Thanks,
Harold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like some characters are not embedded in your textfield (digits 2, 3...).
Select the Textfield, click on Embed and check "Numerals".

Cheers